# Iteration on a Ruby hash, unexpected behavior

Tags: ruby

```
r = {}
r[0] = [1, 2]
r[2] = [1, 2, 4]
r[4] = [1, 2, 5]
r[6] = [1, 2]

count = 0
r.each do |x|
    count += x.length
end 

puts count #output is 8 expected value is 10
```

1. Why this behavior?
2. How to achieve the expected behavior (getting the sum of the length)

Comment: I've achieved the expected behavior by iterating on value rather than on the hash itself. But explanation are still welcomed.

Comment: Try `puts x` inside the loop and see what you have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`each` converts the receiver hash into an array and iterates over it. Each element of that iteration consists of an array of two elements: a key and its corresponding value. Since you have four key-value pairs, that adds up to eight.

To acheive `10`, you can do:

```
r.each do |x|
  count += x.last.length
end
```

or

```
r.each do |_, v|
  count += v.length
end
```

or

```
r.values.flatten.length
```

Comment: The last one looks more elegant, but will have the side-effect of having to process a lot of data for large lists and create a temporary array that's thrown away almost immediately. The best combination of these is: `r.values.inject(0) { |s, v| s + v.length }` or if you have ActiveSupport: `r.values.sum(&:length)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
r = {}
r[0] = [1, 2]
r[2] = [1, 2, 4]
r[4] = [1, 2, 5]
r[6] = [1, 2]
count = 0
r.each do |k,v|
    count += v.length
end 

puts count
# >> 10
```

[Hash#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each) says

> Calls block once for each key in hsh, passing the key-value pair as parameters.

In your case:

```
r = {}
r[0] = [1, 2]
r[2] = [1, 2, 4]
r[4] = [1, 2, 5]
r[6] = [1, 2]
count = 0
r.each do |x|
    p x.length,x
end 

# >> 2
# >> [0, [1, 2]]
# >> 2
# >> [2, [1, 2, 4]]
# >> 2
# >> [4, [1, 2, 5]]
# >> 2
# >> [6, [1, 2]]
```

Your each x is a size of 2 array. Now as you your Hash `r` has 4 keys, thus `4*2` gives the total count of 8.

Comment: This is because `each` on a Hash will iterate over pairs, so 4 * 2 = 8. Expanding them here as `k,v` fixes the issue.

Comment: @tadman exactly true...your one line is the exact and complete answer.

Comment: You replied first and your answer is correct (+1), nevertheless I found the one from @sawa simpler. Thanks however

Answer (score 1):

`r` is a hash, not an array, so #each gives the key and the value to the block. Since the block only takes a single argument, the argument is given as an array.

```
r = {}
r[0] = [1,2,3]

r.each do |x|
  p x #=> [0,[1,2,3]]
end

r.each do |key,value|
  p key #=> 0
  p value #=> [1,2]
end
```